# Take a 4 digit input and change order

Tags: javascript

I am trying to prompt user for a 4 digit number. Then, replace each
digit by (the sum of that digit plus 7) modulus 10. Then swap the first digit with the third, and swap the second digit with the fourth. Then output the encrypted digits. 
So, if i enter in 1234 it should encrypt it to 0189 or enter in 5948 and it encrypt it to 1526

The problem is i get 9810 and 6251. So, its reading it backwards. I am close but its in the wrong order.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    var temp;
    var number;
    var first;
    var second;
    var third;
    var fourth;
    var fifth;
    //prompt for first number

    do {
        inputNumber = window.prompt("Enter only a 4 digit number");
        if ((isNaN(inputNumber) || !(inputNumber.length == 4)))
            window.alert("please enter a number or length of 4");

    } while ((isNaN(inputNumber)) || !(inputNumber.length == 4));

    //temp = inputNumber;

    temp = parseInt(inputNumber);
    first = temp % 10; //process each number one by one
    temp = temp / 10; 
    second = temp % 10; 
    temp = temp / 10;
    third = temp % 10;
    temp = temp / 10;
    fourth = temp % 10;

    swap = first;
    first = third;
    third = swap;

    swap = second;
    second = fourth;
    fourth = swap;

    first = parseInt(first);
    second = parseInt(second);
    third = parseInt(third);
    fifth = parseInt(fifth);
    fourth = parseInt(fourth);

    first = (first + 7) % 10
    second = (second + 7) % 10
    third = (third + 7) % 10
    fourth = (fourth + 7) % 10

   var incrypted = first * 1000 + second * 100 + third * 10 + fourth * 1;
   //var incrypted = first * 1000 + second  + third * 10 + fourth * 1;
    document.writeln("<h1>The number " + inputNumber + " is encrypted as " + incrypted + ".</h1><br />");

</script>
```

Comment: When I take your code and run it with Node.js (which is really the best tool to debug something like this) it says that `fifth` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better off handling your numbers individually.

```
var digits = inputNumber.split("");
digits[0] = (+digits[0]+7)%10;
digits[1] = (+digits[1]+7)%10;
digits[2] = (+digits[2]+7)%10;
digits[3] = (+digits[3]+7)%10;
digits.push(digits.shift());
digits.push(digits.shift());
// rotating by two results in 1234 becoming 3412, same result just more efficient!
var result = digits.join("");
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind, and that I hope this answer has shown you, is that there is always more than one way to solve a problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var num = "1234"
var digits = num.split("");
var out = [];
for(var i=0; i<digits.length; i++){
   digits[i] = (parseInt(digits[i])+7)%10;
}
var end = [digits[2],digits[3],digits[0],digits[1]].join("");
console.log(end.join(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

A shuffle function:

```
function shuffle(val){
    val = val + "";
    function transform(num) { return (+num + 7) % 10 + ""; }

    return  transform(val[2]) +
            transform(val[3]) +
            transform(val[0]) +
            transform(val[1]);
}
```

and with some validation:

```
function shuffle(val){
    val = val + "";
    if(isNaN(val)) throw "a valid number is required";
    if(val.length != 4) throw "a four-digit number is required";

    function transform(num) { return (+num + 7) % 10 + ""; }

    return  transform(val[2]) +
            transform(val[3]) +
            transform(val[0]) +
            transform(val[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to a fundamental misunderstanding of how the `%` operator works.

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) reference states this about the `%` operator:

> The modulo function is the integer remainder of dividing var1 by var2.
>   For example, 12 % 5 returns 2.

Taking your example, with the input `1234`, you are first finding the modulo `10` of `1234` in this code:

```
first = temp % 10;
```

The modulo of `1234` is `4` because `1230` is divisible by `10`, leaving `4` as the remainder.  Thus your logic reversus things.  You could just change things at the beginning of your code to be reversed a bit:

```
fourth = temp % 10; //process each number one by one
temp = temp / 10;.
third = temp % 10;.
temp = temp / 10;
second = temp % 10;
temp = temp / 10;
first = temp % 10;
```

There is still a problem, when fixed as above you code will output `189` as the answer because you are combing the numbers back together with addition arithmetic rather than string concatenation, as in `0 + 1 + 8 + 9 = 189`.  Change that last line to look like this and you are fixed:

```
var incrypted = first + '' + second  + '' + third + '' + fourth;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me;

```
<script>
    var vec = new Array("1","2","3","4");

    for(var i = 0; i<4; ++i){
        vec[i] = (+vec[i] + 7) % 10;
    }

    var tmp = vec[1];
    vec[1] = vec[3];
    vec[3] = tmp;

    vec = vec.reverse();

    tmp = Number(vec.splice(0,1));

    vec.push(tmp);

    console.log("vec:", vec);
</script>
```

logs `vec: [0, 1, 8, 9]`